# Arduino to Processing Long datatype over serial OutofBoundsException

Tags: arduino, serial-port, processing, indexoutofboundsexception, long-integer

I am trying to transfer long values over serial from Arduino to processing, and have the following code.

Arduino:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  long int randomno = random(0, 1520);
  unsigned char buf[sizeof(long int)];
  memcpy(buf,&randomno,sizeof(long int));
  Serial.write(buf,sizeof(buf));
  delay(50);
}
```

And processing:

```
import processing.serial.*;
Serial myPort;

void setup() {
  size(1920, 1080);
  myPort = new Serial(this, "COM3", 9600);
}

void draw(){
  background(0,0,0);
   long value;
   byte[] inBuffer = new byte[4];

  if (myPort.available() > 0) {
    try{
    inBuffer = myPort.readBytes();
    if (inBuffer != null) {
         value = byteAsULong(inBuffer[0]) << 0 | 
         (byteAsULong(inBuffer[1])) << 8 | 
         (byteAsULong(inBuffer[2])) << 16| 
         (byteAsULong(inBuffer[3])) << 24;
      println(value);
    }
    } catch(RuntimeException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}

public static long byteAsULong(byte b) {
    return ((long)b) & 0x00000000000000FFL; 
}
```

When I run this, I get a few values, but then keep getting ArrayIndexOutofBounds Exceptions thrown at me. For now I have overcome it by using a printstacktrace catch, but I want to find out what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

A `long` in Arduino is 32 bits unsigned or signed.  The value `0x00000000000000FF` is a 64-bit number and is not comprehensible in the Arduino architecture. That function doesn't seem to serve any purpose when you can simply do::

```
value = inBuffer[0] | 
        inBuffer[1] << 8 | 
        inBuffer[2] << 16| 
        inBuffer[3] << 24;
```